# Vivado error Using Verilog. Implementation Error - IO placement is infeasible

Tags: verilog, vivado

Implementation Error - [Place 30-58] IO placement is infeasible.
Hi I have been struggling with completing this assignment I have been working since I don't know how to get past this implementation error.
Everytime I think things will work I am receiving the error IO placement is infeasible. Number of s(100).

I have been following all the guidelines to my project and am extremely confused on how I am supposed to get over this error.

The following is the top level module that is supposed to track the first stages of my pipelined process.

Top level module I/O -

```
module datapath(clk, pc, dinstOut, ewreg, em2reg, ewmem, ealuc, ealuimm, edestReg, eqa, eqb, eimm32);
input clk;
output wire [31:0] pc;
output wire [31:0] dinstOut;
output wire ewreg;
output wire em2reg;
output wire ewmem;
output wire [3:0] ealuc;
output wire ealuimm;
output wire [4:0] edestReg;
output wire [31:0] eqa;
output wire [31:0] eqb;
output wire [31:0] eimm32;
```

The part I am using is XC7Z010-CLG400-1

This is the error I am receiving -

[Place 30-58] IO placement is infeasible. Number of unplaced IO Ports (173) is greater than number of available sites (100).
The following are banks with available pins:
IO Group: 1 with : SioStd: LVCMOS18   VCCO = 1.8 Termination: 0  TermDir:  Out  RangeId: 2 Drv: 12  has only 100 sites available on device, but needs 173 sites.

```
Term: dinstOut[0]
    Term:  dinstOut[1] .....
    Term:  dinstOut[31]
    Term:  eimm32[0] .......
    Term:  eimm32[31]
    Term:  eqa[0] .......
    Term:  eqa[31]
    Term:  eqb[0]  ......
    Term:  eqb[31]
    Term:  pc[0]   .......
    Term:  pc[31]
    Term:  edestReg[0]
    Term:  edestReg[1]
    Term:  edestReg[2]
    Term:  edestReg[3]
    Term:  edestReg[4]
    Term:  ealuc[0]
    Term:  ealuc[1]
    Term:  ealuc[2]
    Term:  ealuc[3]
    Term:  ealuimm
    Term:  em2reg
    Term:  ewmem
    Term:  and ewreg
```

Any help is super useful! Please I am in despair

I was expecting everything to be wired properly as the RTL analysis showed, but have only gotten implementation errors every time i have tried to run the implementation. I feel like whatever I try is not working.

Comment: @Mikef Hey thanks for the advice, Im fairly new with vivado, but I do not believe I have a constraints file. When looking at all my sources, the constraints file is empty so I am unsure on what you mean by that part

Answer (score 0):

The tools are telling you that the design does not physically fit in the targeted FPGA device.
Specifically, the error messages indicates the RTL design needs 173 IO pins, however the hardware device has only 100 IO pins.

Options to fix the error:

1. Change the number of IO pins used by the RTL to 100 or less.   One way is to change all the busses from 32 bits to 16 (that would get you under 100).
2. Change the tool settings to target a part with more IO, for example the XC7Z100 in the FFG1156 package has 250 HR select IO.
3. Use some of the interfaces between the PL & PS to implement some of the behavior currently modeled to use PL io pins (this is probably the most complex solution because in involves software running on the PS).

See
[ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview)  Table 2 and Table 3 to get the number of IO available in each part/package combination.